# CakePHP3 - CSS and JS not loading after git push to server

Tags: css, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have develop a CakePHP application on my local machine and the CSS and JS work fine. When I push the git respiratory to OpenShift however, the CSS and JS do not load. I have searched the site and concluded that there is a problem with one of my .htaccess files. I have tried the default files listed in the CakePHP manual, but it does not seem to work. Here is what I got.

[root directory]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ReWriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

src

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$    /    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /$1    [L]
   AllowOverride All
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did mod rewrite enabled on your server ?

Comment: mod_rewrite is already enabled.

Comment: Can you also post your vhost file content ? maybe you need you enable allow overwrite for that folder. 
are you able to use other urls except home page ?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I erroneously saved the webroot .htaccess to the wrong directory to my machine. This has to be the cause of the problem. I am certain the page will load properly once I push the file to the server.